# How to Replace Labels Dynamically application wise in asp.net (as per session )?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have C# application with 10-20 pages.
Here I need to Update label as per session.

For Example,
If I Have Used Some Static Word "Community" in many places.
When Session's Value is "A" it should display "Community"
And For Session Value B it should display "People"

Is there any way in C# or Asp.Net like we have Localization ?

I need to update those labels globally.
So I am not expecting if-else case at all places.

I Have to implement this in my application.
I am asking for the ways to do that which i am not able to find other than (if..else)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How this question is unusefull ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can change the various page, you can create a custom Label `Control` that will do what you want.

```
public class CustomLabel : Label
{
    public override String Text
    {
        get
        {
            ModeType mode = this.Context.Session["Mode"];
            if (mode == ModeType.People)
            {
                return "People";
            }
            else
            {
                return "Community";
            }
        }
        set
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Then register the control on the web.config :

```xml
<system.web>
    <pages>
        <controls>
            <add tagPrefix="custom" namespace="YourProject.Web.UI.WebControls" 
                 assembly="YourProject.Web" />
        </controls>
    </pages>
</system.web>
```

And use `<custom:CustomLabel runat="server" ...` instead of `<asp:label ...`

If you can't change your tagMapping. It is a mechanism that will replace all controls of a specified type with another. Use the following config on your web.config :

```xml
<system.web>
    <pages>
        <tagMapping>
            <add tagType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label" 
                 mappedTagType="YourProject.Web.UI.WebControls.CustomLabel" />
        </tagMapping>
    </pages>
</system.web>
```

Of course, you will have to change the code of `CustomLabel` to replace only label that target your requirement.

Another solution would be to recursively modify all Label on the Render method of the base page. It requires that all pages have a common base page.

```
public class BasePage : Page
{
    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        this.ReplaceLabel(this); 
        base.Render(writer);

    }

    private void ReplaceLabel(Control control)
    {
        if (control is Label)
        {
            Label lbl = (Label)control;
            if (lbl.Text == "Community")
            {
                ModeType mode = this.Context.Session["Mode"];
                if (mode == ModeType.People)
                {
                    lbl.Text = "People";
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (Control childControl in control.Controls)
            {
                this.ReplaceLabel(childControl);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't have a base page for all your page (which is a good practice) and you can't add it. You can do the same on a HttpModule :

```
public class CustomModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += context_BeginRequest;
    }

    private void context_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Handler is Page)
        {
            Page page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
            page.PreRenderComplete += page_PreRenderComplete;
        }
    }

    private void page_PreRenderComplete(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page page = (Page)sender;
        this.ReplaceLabel(page);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    { }


    private void ReplaceLabel(Control control)
    {
        if (control is Label)
        {
            Label lbl = (Label)control;
            if (lbl.Text == "Community")
            {
                ModeType mode = this.Context.Session["Mode"];
                if (mode == ModeType.People)
                {
                    lbl.Text = "People";
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (Control childControl in control.Controls)
            {
                this.ReplaceLabel(childControl);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And you will have to register it on your web.config this way

```xml
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <add name="customModule" Type="YourProject.Web.CustomModule, YourProject.Web" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for understanding the requirement. Even though it is a genuine question some uses find it useless.

Comment: You question have +2 and -2, don't understand why. BTW if the answer resolved your problem, don't forget to mark it as an answer. It will help other person with a similar need

Answer (score 0):

See code below

```css
    public class MyLabel : Label
    {
        public string aSideText { get; set; }
        public string bSideText { get; set; }

    }
```

And this code

```css
MyLabel[] myLabels = { label1, label2, label3 };
            string side = "A";
            foreach (MyLabel myLabel in myLabels)
            {
                if (side == "A")
                {
                    myLabel.Text = myLabel.aSideText;
                }
                else
                {
                    myLabel.Text = myLabel.bSideText;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks. But ours is web application , and also we are having different different pages.So if we are going to add if..else condition on every pages then it's not global solution.we want global solution for all 20 odd pages